# Ejabberd: How to get the admin user configured in ejabberd.yml file

Tags: erlang, yaml, ejabberd

```
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
    user:
      - "******@*****"
```

My ejabberd.yml file has this properties.
I want to get the user value in a module to get Admin user's name.
Since I am new to ejabberd, confused with so many codes which is getting max_user_sessions, shaper_rules etc.
How can I do this?

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the admin user configured in ejabberd.yml file

If the account "user1" is registered in the vhost "localhost" and you want to grant it admin rights, configure like this in ejabberd.yml:

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - user1@localhost
```

Comment: I have to get user1@localhost inside my module. How can I do it?